# sql lookup id's vs fixed string

Tags: sql, foreign-keys

I have a quote status which is either DRAFT, SENT, WON or LOST. Normally I would create a lookup table with Id, Name and then link across via quote_status_id but in this case as the statuses are system managed e.g. users can't create statuses, is it better to use the string instead?

FYI in my particular case I am developing a rest api and multiple front ends e.g. SPA and mobile app so I need to keep the statuses in sync between backend and front end but there are some user workflows depending on status. This probably doesn't affect my initial question but I'm wondering if the string might simplify my development even slightly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You absolutely want to favour lookup tables instead of fixed strings. There are a whole raft of maintainability reasons for using lookup tables, but for me it comes down to one core value which is data security.

In any full-stack application, you have trust your database data the most, as it's the most persistent. In line with this ideology, you want to build your database in such a way that makes it as **difficult as possible** for data to end up in an invalid state. Foreign keys are incredibly powerful at supporting this, because you can do a number of things including:

- Ensuring that quotes always have a valid status (if that's your desire)
- Preventing any user/developer spelling errors from persisting the database (e.g. creating a "droft" quote status)
- Easily updating the display name in a single place (so "Won" could be changed to "Acquired" if you needed it to and you wouldn't have to check for every reference in your codebase)

Free-text fields in databases should be primarily reserved for exactly that, free-text. If the values are pre-defined and should never change, then lookup tables are the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

The string is fine.  An id and reference table has the nice advantage that you can verify the spelling and values that go in to the field.  In addition, if the status is stored in multiple tables, then a reference table ensures that the same values are used in all referencing tables.

However, for values in a single table, a `check` constraint works almost as well:

```
alter table t add constraint chk_t_status check (status in ('DRAFT', 'SENT', 'WON', 'LOST'));
```

Comment: One of the disadvantages to using check constraints is that you lose some future maintainability. Say you wanted to add a description for each status, now you've got to create an additional column on your table with repeat data. I'm not saying the answer is wrong, but as a DBA I prefer to approach design with an "expect everything to change in 6 months" attitude. You get backed into hacky fixes far less often that way.